# Searching for files in a specified directory

Tags: python, exception-handling, python-3.x, search

I am currently writing a program that allows me to search for files in a user-specified directory. My current code is as follows:

```
if os.path.exists(file_path)!= True:
    print('\n******* Path does not exist. *******\n')       

else:
    while True:
        aa = '''\nWhich search characteristics would you like to use? \n 1. Search by name: N \n 2. Search by extension: E \n 3. Search by size: S
            \n    Please enter your choice: '''

        answer = input(aa).strip()

        if answer not in 'NnEeSs' or answer=='':
            print('\n***** Invalid choice. *****')

        elif answer in 'Nn':
            while True:
                try:
                    name = input ('\nEnter file name: ')
                    rr = search_by_name(name, file_path)
                    if not rr:
                        print('\n***** File not found *****\n')
                    else:
                        break

                except WindowsError:
                    print('\n***** Oops! Access denied.*****\n')
                    continue


        elif answer in 'Ee':
            while True:
                try:
                    ending = input ('\nEnter the file extension: ')
                    rr = search_by_extention(ending, file_path)
                    if not rr:
                        print('\n***** No File(s) found *****\n')
                    else:
                        break

                except WindowsError:
                    print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                    continue              

        elif answer in 'Ss':
            while True:
                try:
                    size = int(input('\nPlease enter file size: '))
                    rr = search_by_size(size, file_path)
                    if not rr:
                        print('\n***** No file(s) found *****\n')
                    else:
                        break

                except ValueError:
                    print('\n***** Enter an numeric value. *****\n')
                    continue

                except WindowsError:
                    print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                    continue
```

Each of the search functions returns a list containing the result.

The `try` and `except` statements are concerning, and I feel they can be improved.

In each of these cases, or generally, how can the code be improved, or simplified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve readability I would try and break the code down into more functions and redefine your pre-determined text values as globals, such that you can save space in the actual function. Responses can be represented by a dictionary value with boolean/text key value pairs (or exception/text). Also certain UI options can be stored in a dictionary, with links to their associated functions.

```
# using 3 quotes mean you don't need to specify newlines
dir_tools_menu = '''
Which search characteristics would you like to use?
1. Search by name: N 
2. Search by extension: E 
3. Search by size: S
\tPlease enter your choice: '''
dir_tools_options = {"n":ui_search_by_name, 
                     "e":ui_search_by_extention, 
                     "s":ui_search_by_size}
error_response = {WindowsError:"Oops! Access denied.", 
                  ValueError:"Enter an numeric value."}
# add number of files for true
files_found_response = {False:"No file(s) found", 
                        True:"{} file(s) found"}
# add filename
file_found_response = {False:"File {} not found",
                       True:"File {} found"}
file_exists_response ={ False:"Path does not exist.", 
                         True:"Path Found"}
# add choice for true
valid_ui_response = {False:"Invalid choice.", 
                      True:"You choose {}."}
```

Now that we have a collection of text values lets make a function to standardize print outputs, such that you don't have to write all those stars everywhere, and you can feel assured that they will produce even length lines.

```
line_length = 40
# or you can have a funky pattern like "`-._.-'-._...
line_pad = "*"*line_length 

def my_print(text, *params):
    # len(params) must match the count of "{}" in the text so this will not crash
    # Perhaps add a check to assert this case
    message = text.format(*params)
    offset = line_length/2 - len(message)/2
    if offset > 0 and offset + len(message) < line_length:
        print(line_pad[:offset] + message + line_pad[offset+len(message):])
    # in the case that a line is larger than the formatting, you can just print the line.
    # its gonna look gross regardless
    else:
        print(message)
```

Lets also make a simple yes/no function.

```
yes = ("yes", "y","1")
no = ("no", "n", "0")
def ask_yes_no(question):
    answer = ''
    while not answer in yes + no:
        answer = input(question).lower()
        if not answer in yes + no:
            my_print(valid_ui_response[False])
        else:
            my_print(valid_ui_response[True], return_to_menu)
            # True - yes, False - no
            return answer in yes
```

Now your main method boils down to..

```
quit_question = "Quit Dir Tools? "

def dir_tools(file_path):
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        my_print(file_exists_response[True] )
    else:
        my_print(file_exists_response[False])
        return
    quit_dir_tools = False
    while not quit_dir_tools:
        answer = input(dir_tools_menu).lower()
        if answer not in dir_tools_options:
            my_print(valid_ui_response[False])
        else:
            my_print(valid_ui_response[True],answer)
            dir_tools_options[answer](file_path)
        quit_dir_tools = ask_yes_no(quit_question)
```

Now for the actual important functions.. I'll just do one example to show the try catch responses,..

```
ui_sbn_question = 'Enter file name: '
return_question = "Return to main menu? "

def ui_search_by_name(file_path):
    return_to_menu = False
    while not return_to_menu:
        name = input(ui_sbn_question)
        try:
            sbn_response = search_by_name(name, file_path)
            if not sbn_response:
                my_print(file_found_response[False], name)
            else:
                my_print(file_found_response[True], name)
                # assuming that this isnt a boolean
                my_print(sbn_response)
        except WindowsError:
            my_print(error_response[WindowsError])
        return_to_menu = ask_yes_no(return_question)
```

Comment: http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

Overall, you need to look into PEP 8. Other then that, you need to apply a strategy pattern to get rid of redundant `if`/`else` loop. See more detailed analysis below.

## Line by line analysis

```
if os.path.exists(file_path)!= True:
```

Use `if not var`.

```
    print('\n******* Path does not exist. *******\n')
```

You have too many new lines in your code.

```
else:
    while True:
        aa = '''\nWhich search characteristics would you like to use? \n 1. Search by name: N \n 2. Search by extension: E \n 3. Search by size: S
            \n    Please enter your choice: '''
```

Wrap your code in 80 columns. Also, what kind of name is `aa`? Pick a meaningful name.

```
        answer = input(aa).strip()

        if answer not in 'NnEeSs' or answer=='':
```

`if answer.lower() not in ('n', 'e', 's')` is more readable. You don't need to check if it's empty either.

```
            print('\n***** Invalid choice. *****')

        elif answer in 'Nn':
            while True:
                try:
                    name = input ('\nEnter file name: ')
```

No space after `input`.

```
                    rr = search_by_name(name, file_path)
```

Pick a better variable name.

```
                    if not rr:
                        print('\n***** File not found *****\n')
                    else:
                        break

                except WindowsError:
                    print('\n***** Oops! Access denied.*****\n')
                    continue
```

No need for continue here.

```
        elif answer in 'Ee':
            while True:
                try:
                    ending = input ('\nEnter the file extension: ')
                    rr = search_by_extention(ending, file_path)
                    if not rr:
                        print('\n***** No File(s) found *****\n')
                    else:
                        break

                except WindowsError:
                    print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                    continue              

        elif answer in 'Ss':
            while True:
                try:
                    size = int(input('\nPlease enter file size: '))
```

`ValueError` should be caught here, not down the road. Make your exception catches as narrow as you can.

```
                    rr = search_by_size(size, file_path)
                    if not rr:
                        print('\n***** No file(s) found *****\n')
                    else:
                        break

                except ValueError:
                    print('\n***** Enter an numeric value. *****\n')
                    continue

                except WindowsError:
                    print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                    continue
```

The `continue` statements are redundant here.

## Suggested improvements

You can use a strategy pattern to get around having all the `if`/`else` constructs. You can define `OPERATIONS` dict, with your operation identifier as keys and `(method_to_be_called, message_to_be_displayed)` as values.

```
OPERATIONS = {
    'n': ('search_by_name', 'Enter the file name'),
    'e': ('search_by_extension', 'Enter the extension'),
    's': ('search_by_size', 'Enter the size'),
    }

if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    print('\n******* Path does not exist. *******\n')
    return  # This way the rest of your code has to be indented less.
while True:
   question = (
       "\nWhich search characteristics would you like to use? "
       "\n 1. Search by name: N "
       "\n 2. Search by extension: E "
       "\n 3. Search by size: S "
       "\n    Please enter your choice:"
       )
   answer = input(question).strip().lower()
   if answer not in OPERATIONS:
       print('\n***** Invalid choice. *****')
       continue
   method, operation_question = OPERATIONS[answer]
   while True:
       value = input(operation_question).strip()
       if answer == 's':  # Search by size.
           try:
               value = int(value)
           except ValueError:
               print('\n***** Enter an numeric value. *****\n')
               continue
       try:
           # This line gets and executes relevant method from the current
           # module (that is what __import__(__name__) stands for).
           result = getattr(__import__(__name__), method)(value, file_path)
       except WindowsError:
           print('\n***** Oops! Access denied.*****\n')
           continue
       if result:
           # Perform actions with a result.
           break
       print('\n***** File not found *****\n')
```